# How to Disable Native Language support in make

Tags: makefile

I get errors when running `make` and I would like to ask for help on a forum.

However I'm not an English native and get The Output in my language.

How can I make `make` display the output in English.

Comment: I meant that 'make' outputted data in German istead of English.

Comment: What operating system are you running make on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For linux this should do:

```
LANG=C make
```

and this should work for cygwin shell aswell.

For Gnu Make for Windows, i found this to work:
navigate to `(Make Install Dir)\share\locale` (for me it is
`C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\share\locale`)
in this folder, there are a lot of folders, for each language supported by make. if you want make to not use your native language, you can rename the folder with your language code (de for German) so make won't find it, and default back to English.
 for example, i renamed the folder `he` (my language code) to `he.old`, and make  is now in english for me.